# What DataCenter ISPs support IPv6

Tags: ipv6

Which are the major ISPs out there that support IPv6 traffic?

Comment: It might help to know where you're looking, or do you mean globally?

Comment: I am concerned with US and Europe. I am specifically looking to host servers in a datacenter with ISPs that support IPv6. Not all ISPs support (consumer or enterprise or datacenter) I am aware of it - so of course not globally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hurricane Electric is the biggest evangelist -- they'll often give you discounts for running dual stack compared to v4 only. Other carriers include Global Crossing, Verizon Business (on some routers; can be a hassle), Level3, nLayer, Sprint (new offering, may still be working kinks out).

Here's a longer list:
http://www.sixxs.net/faq/connectivity/?faq=ipv6transit

Answer (score 0):

IP Exchange, Germany, Nürnberg got me a /56 within an hour after asking for it ;)

Not cheap, no servers (only partial racks - 1/4 minimum).... 71gbit external bandwidth last time I asked ;)

Answer (score 0):

Leaseweb supports IPv6 as well, though they don't really advertise it. You have to ask for an IPv6 address once you have a server, but they answer quickly.

Answer (score 0):

IPExchange, SpaceNet and Level 3 are known to me.